# Java IDE for Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, ide

Anyone know a good Java IDE for the Pi? I tried downloading Eclipse but it didn't work (probably because it's too heavyweight). I need an IDE with low RAM usage and low memory usage, just so it will actually work :) Help appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there's any, but why would you want to run a Java IDE on the Pi? If you want to develop applications for the Pi, you can still run the IDE on your computer and test your app on the Pi - I can give more details if you want.

Comment: Blaisorblade, yes please, more details.  I'm guessing we can compile everything on a pc but I'm fuzzy about how to package everything for running on the pi.  Others might even more info if they'e not familiar with eclipse.

Comment: good points both of you - i want to program on the pi because my laptop is horrendously slow :)

Comment: I suggest that you use Ant. It makes it easy to compile without a lot of typing at the command line.

Comment: @imulsion, is your laptop older than a pentium 300?

Comment: update: BlueJ now supports the Raspberry Pi. see my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple lightweight IDE is **Geany**.

```
apt-get install geany
```

Geany - support:
java syntax highlight,
geany projects to store custom javac compile and java run arguments if needed, you need to specify -classpath to include external java libraries.
one button compile/run.

I also recommend looking at **DrJava**, it is also a lightweight IDE written entirely in Java Swing.
DrJava got a built-in powerful "interactive" mode that allows quick experimentation with java expressions similar to using interactive python, thus suitable for use by new java students.
DrJava support breakpoint debugging and junit test creation.
Installation is a snap you download the latest DrJava .jar and run it:

```
java -jar drjava-stable-20120818-r5686.jar
```

http://www.drjava.org/

Comment: thank you! can't believe this question was closed at one point...

Comment: Just my opinion as a professional Java programmer just trying something on a Pi: Geany is a piece 'o crap and DrJava is an equal piece 'o crap. Both have no usable content assistant or organize imports feature.

Answer (score 2):

Going a step further from one of the earlier answers and imho an easier alternative:

NO NEED FOR AN IDE   :)  keep eclipse-like memory hogs off your pi.  Or if you really want to be more hardcore, use vim or emacs with syntax highlighting and compile your .java files to .class files via command-line with javac.  Or find some light-weight IDE or sublime text / eclipse replacement.  However... if you have a stronger alternative system at your disposal (which I suspect most of us have) and can run eclipse on there, then there's no need for extra work.

- you can develop a java program on any other IDE on another system
- once you have your program ready, export it as a runnable jar file
- copy this jar over to your pi (through SCP if on the same network or flashdrive)
- run this jar on your pi (java -jar [yourJarName.jar])

Caveats:
java compatability between where you developed and with the JRE from the pi (or else you'll get the unsupported major/minor exception)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/raspberrypi/index.html), it is now optimized for running on the Raspberry Pi.

> From version 3.14, BlueJ fully supports the Raspberry Pi

Comment: BlueJ requires JavaFX. Arm distros of Java JDK don't have JavaFX. What the...

Comment: Oracle removed the support of JavaFX on ARM with the JDK8u33 at the time of writing this response it was still supported. So you can simply install an older oracle JDK, compile the JDK by yourself and add the support back in or maybe switch to openJDK (not sure if it is supported there).

Answer (score -4):

BlueJ is the one. It is the best for beginner's level.

Comment: Can you edit and expand your answer to provide a link, a better description and reasons why it is _the best_?